# Wha does “Sunday out “ means

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Thisis from Woody Allen movie - Manhattan - Hello Yale, I am sorry for calling ...
Well,no,no nothings wrong 
Well I just thought that it”s Sunday out
and maybe if you could get away we could go for a walk or ..

My question is why did they say “Sunday out rather than “Sunday”

Comment: As a non-native speaker's view, I guess here **"out"** is used as a noun meaning **"an outing"** and Sunday is modifying **"out"**, but as there is no article attached to **"Sunday out"**, I think it seems to be used as a fixed expression as a whole for an Sunday outing, and its similar expression would be **"Sunday off"**.

Comment: Are you sure this wasn't, "... it's **sunny** out ..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means *it's Sunday* ***outside***.

---

It's like saying *it's raining out* which simply means it's raining outside. Or *it's cold out*, which just indicates the outdoor temperature.

*Out* is unnecessary for the literalism of the expression, however it's often used in a way to figuratively express that fact that the person saying it, or the person being told it, is *inside* and currently unaffected by the situation.

If you're indoors, then your inside world (dry or warm) is different from the outside world (wet or cold).

---

Similarly, if you've taken a week off work and have holed up in your home, what particular day it is *outside in the real world* may be something that either isn't affecting you or you may actually be unaware of. Without the need to check a calendar or perform any day-based tasks, and in an extreme case, you may actually be unaware of what day it is.

Without knowing the specific context of this movie (I haven't seen it), the person being called, Yale, might have secluded themself indoors for a prolonged period of time, and the caller is simply letting them know what day it is *outside in the real world*.

Or *out* could just have been thrown in as a manner of speaking in the same way that *it's raining out* or *it's cold out* is often said, even though, strictly speaking, the *out* part is redundant.

Comment: I would add that "It's [adjective] out" is often used with the implied meaning that it's specifically good (or sometimes specifically bad) weather for going outside to do activities. (E.g. "it's sunny out", "it's warm out", "it's nice out", or on the opposite end "it's rainy out", "it's cold out".) Especially in context here, I think the intended implication of "it's Sunday out" is that Sunday is a good day for going outside. (Or possibly that the caller -- who is clearly trying to encourage Yale to go outside -- is deliberately giving a fairly transparent excuse for why he should.)